# Migration to 1.0.0 MessageKit Cocoapod with MessagesLayoutDelegate

Tags: ios, messagekit

When I try to upgrade to v1.0.0 of MessageKit, I get the following errors:

[image]

I'd be appreciative of a migration path to convert this to the new API. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there has been a change made to the `LabelAlignment` Class. It no longer has predefined `.messageLeading` but instead has a property for the textAlignment as a part of the `LabelAlignment` object. If you hold `Command` and click the `LabelAlignment` you can see its definition.

```swift
public var textAlignment: NSTextAlignment
public var textInsets: UIEdgeInsets
```

So all you need to do is adjust yours calls to the new constructor.

```swift
func cellTopLabelAlignment(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> LabelAlignment {
    if isFromCurrentSender(message: message) {
        return LabelAlignment(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.left, textInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10))
    }
    return LabelAlignment(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.right, textInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10))
}
```

If you want to find out all the changes that have happed in each release check out the [ChangeLog here](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try!

Comment: I also had to explicitly `import MessageInputBar`.

Comment: Well, in the end it seems I didn't need the `cellTopLabelAlignment` method any more and it looks like it's been removed from the delegate any ways. See also https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/issues/1041